# Trouble with external monitor in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, monitor

I'm getting this error when I want to configure an external monitor to connect it to my laptop.

requested position/size for CRTC 148 is outside the allowed limit: position=(1366, 0), size=(1366, 768), maximum=(1600, 1600)

Does any one know how to fix this?

Comment: I got the same message except for maximum=(2048,2048).

Comment: Still I couldn't solve it and I use mirroring screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your virtual screen is 1600x1600, but you are trying to squeeze two screens into it. Each screen is 1366, so you need virtual screen 2732x768 or bigger.

Option 1.
Remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot with external monitor attached. Recent X works well without `xorg.conf`.

Option 2.
Fix virtual desktop size in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same message for maximum=(2048,2048), one monitor 1440x900, the other one 1336x768, the solution I've found is to put on on top of the other, so it will be 1440x1668, or, use Ubuntu 2D and in that desktop I've saw no resolution limitations...

You can also try jupiter to enable both monitors... I've tried it without luck, but I think there are tricks that need to be done with jupiter like enable both monitores BEFORE plugg the second one in!

Sory for my bad english and good luck with that!
If you find a better solution post it here so I can try it too!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions in this link:
http://blog.jvc26.org/2011/09/29/multimonitor-ubuntu-oneiric-fglrx

It worked perfectly for me :D

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.